# How to loop through database table to add data in datagrid?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid, logic

I have code to read from database table to datagrid but it only runs once and adds the top row to the datagrid from database. Is there a way I can run it multiple times to read the data from different rows and add it in my datagrid.

```
 public static void AddData( DataGrid datagrid)
 {
        SqlConnection connect = GetConnection();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;

        //connect to database
        connect.Open();
        command.CommandText = "Select req_status From TH_request where req_status = 'N'";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        status = (String)command.ExecuteScalar();
        connect.Close();

        connect.Open();
        command.CommandText = "Select req_date_time From TH_request where req_status = 'N'";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        time = (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
        connect.Close();

        connect.Open();
        command.CommandText = "Select resp_user_name From TH_request where req_status = 'N'";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        locationName = (String)command.ExecuteScalar();
        connect.Close();

        collection.Add(new DataObject()
        {
             A = time,
             B = locationName,
             C = status,
             D = respUserName
        });
        datagrid.ItemsSource = collection;

}
```

Comment: Select statement could be followed by more than one field name. _Select req_status, req_date_time,resp_user_name from.... where ...._ Then you use SqlDataReader to get the fields from the returned resultset. This is basic ADO.NET programming. Probably you should stop a bit in your coding efforts and review some tutorial on ADO.NET.

Comment: You should *really* start with some tutorials on this.  You're already querying the database *three times* when you only need to *once*.  Wrapping this in a loop is just going to query it a ton more times.  Instead, query the database *once* to get the full result set that you need and then bind the UI control(s) to that result set.

Comment: Your code will work.  The DGV isn't updating so you need to use a trick.  simply datagrid.ItemsSource = null; and then datagrid.ItemsSource = collection;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have to execute a single command once. You could then for example use a `SqlDataReader` to create a `DataObject` for each row that was returned from the query:

```
public static void AddData(DataGrid datagrid)
{
    collection.Clear();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select req_status, req_date_time, resp_user_name From TH_request where req_status = 'N'", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    collection.Add(new DataObject()
                    {
                        A = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["req_date_time"]),
                        B = Convert.ToString(reader["resp_user_name"]),
                        C = Convert.ToString(reader["req_status"]),
                        D = respUserName
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
    datagrid.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```